# GlassFish: How to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: glassfish, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I am using the latest version of GlassFish. I want to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in response so that my API which is hosted on GlassFish can be called from any domain. But I am not able to find out where to set it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In my case, the API requests are exclusively handled by Jersey, therefore I can set response headers in a `ContainerResponseFilter`:

```
package my.app;

import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

public class CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest creq, ContainerResponse cresp) {

        cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
        cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");

        return cresp;
    }
}
```

The filter gets enabled in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Gateway Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>my.app.CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

If you don't use Jersey, I guess you can create a similar servlet response filter.

Comment: can you add an example on how to do this without jersey?

Comment: Well, for CXF the method described in the post not work, because the ContainerRequestFilter from jax-rs 2.0 API does not extend/implement from Filter, and hence cant be configured as a servlet filter. Trying to do so would result in class cast exception.

Comment: How this answer was accepted if there is no ContainerResponseFilter in java ee 6?

Answer (score 9):

The best and easiest way of doing this, is right click on the project

[image: Create new in project]

and select *Cross-Origin Resource Sharing Filter*

[image: Create new Cross-origin filter]

Comment: If the entry is not in the context menu, choose “Other…”, then filter the list of options by typing “cross”. From now on you can access it from the context menu as described by Leonardo.

Comment: This!!! I don't know why this isn't mentioned more often. Works like a charm and takes only 1 second

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Java EE standard way to do it.  It's almost exactly the same as the Jersey example except for the library packages used (javax) and the method call to get the headers is different (getHeaders).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class RestResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter{

@Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException{
        responseContext.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseContext.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        responseContext.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
        responseContext.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
    }

}
```

Comment: What about web.xml in glassfish 4.1?

Answer (score 2):

Since you use the tag java-ee-6, I believe @Provider isn't supported. I used the following code, based on the [javaee6 tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebFilter(filterName = "AddHeaderFilter", urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class ResponseFilter implements Filter {

  private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ResponseFilter.class.getName() );

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
      log.info("Adding headers");
      HttpServletResponse http = (HttpServletResponse) response;
      http.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      http.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      http.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
    } 
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Good alternative, although it is significantly slower than the @Provider (figured it was worth pointing out)