# Jersey 2 request filter are not working in this code

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have implemented an annotation using the Jersey 2, but somehow the code is not reaching that point.

These are my classes :

Secured

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;

@NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Secured { }
```

SecureImplementation:

```
import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Secured
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class SecureImplementation implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
  @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws 
  IOException {
        System.out.println("Inside Something");
        throw new WebApplicationException(Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
}
}
```

TestingClass

```
@Path("/checkClass")
public class TestingClass{

    @Secured
    @Path("/checkFilter")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Map<String, String> testing(Input input)
            throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        responseMap.put("result","Success");
        return responseMap;
   }
  }
```

It is giving me a response instead of giving me a 401 Error. So, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: where is the code to return 401 error? Are you trying to use filters to send 401 error?

Comment: where is `GetAllAvailableCandidateList`  defined? inside class `extends ResourceConfig`?

Comment: @AmidalaSivaKumar Yes, I am using it in the line throw new WebApplicationException(Status.UNAUTHORIZED); on the SecureImplementation

Comment: @user7294900 Sorry, there was a typo now it is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually `TestingClass` should be registered inside application class together with the filter, e.g.:

```
@ApplicationPath("checkClass")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication () {
        register(TestingClass.class);
        register(SecureImplementation.class);
    }
}


@Path("/checkFilter")
public class TestingClass{

    @Secured
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Map<String, String> testing(Input input)
```

Comment: When I am using it in a separate project, I didn't use this type of class but it was still working. So, I thought that this will work in this as well. So do you think I have to add this class ?

Comment: @MaxNewton this is a way to connect filter to jersey path, there are others, as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893529/how-can-i-create-filter-or-handler-in-restjersey-for-wrapping-jax-rs-requests

Comment: Ok, I will check the other answer

Comment: @MaxNewton you seem to use annotations, so you can add `@ApplicationPath("checkClass")` to `MyApplication` and move `@Path("/checkFilter")` to `TestingClass` declaration

Comment: I tried doing this, changed my web.xml and and this my new class now :
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
 
 public MyApplication()
 {
  packages("com.test");
 }
}

Still the filters are not working