# AngularJS not able to access localhost:8080

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to access JSON from http://localhost:8080/daddy/. This page is powered by glassfish server in the background. I am able to access this url from browser and I get the following result:

```
{"id":11,"content":"Hello, World!"}
```

But when I try to access it from AngularJS i get the following result:

```
{"data":null,"status":0,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://localhost:8080/daddy/","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}
```

******* AngularJS Script ********

```
app.controller("HttpController", ['$http', function($http){

        var currentInstance = this;

        currentInstance.data = {};

    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/daddy/'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        currentInstance.data = response;

      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        currentInstance.data = response ;    
      });

}]);
```

But when I use any public url for getting JSON, it returns just fine. There seems to be a problem with the localhost. Any help will be grateful!

Comment: Is there any error message in the debugger console?

Comment: should it not be `response.data` in your success callback?

Comment: @TheLazyChap `data` seems to be `null`

Comment: @PSWai I'm curious as to why because I've always used it as that in Angular to fetch the data, unless I'm use a service where the promise was already returning  `return response.data;` in which case the response would be correct. It just seems odd he is getting the json back hitting that url directly and not the get it when using the $http call.

Comment: @TheLazyChap `status` is 0, so it means no response. CORS is very likely the issue here. (console will log this if that's really the case)

Comment: @Nikhil You should check the server logs, if you have the access to them. You may also check the console in your web browser, since it should tell you if there are any errors

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, I don't see any json file? for example :

```
  $http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/daddy/file.json'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    currentInstance.data = response;

  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    currentInstance.data = response ;    
  });
```

Are you running the app on the localhost too and will you be deploying it along with the json, if so then why are you linking to it via localhost? why not

```
    $get('../daddy/file.json/').then(function(response)){

    });
```

I am fairly new to angular, but maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a cross origin request problem that you have. Please be sure that CORS is enabled for your Glassfish application: [GlassFish: How to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343892/glassfish-how-to-set-access-control-allow-origin-header)