# CORS issue on angular in ionic 3 and glassfish with javaEE6 on server side

Tags: angular, ionic3, java-7, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I have an issue with ionic3 framework when I run "ionic serve" and I make a request to a localhost server. The error I receive is:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/myrestapi/myendpoint' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have searched around and I have added the Access-Control-Allow both in my server and in angular. From the angular point of view I have the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class Gateway {
    private getBasicHttpOptions(): any {
        let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        let httpOptions: any = {headers: headers};

        return httpOptions;
    }

    public getData(myparam: string): Observable<any> {

        let httpOptions: any = this.getBasicHttpOptions();

        let body: any = {
            'param': myparam
        };

        return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/myrestapi/myendpoint", body, httpOptions);
    }
}
```

And then on the server side I have the following (javeEE6, SDK 7, glassfish 3.1.2):

```
@Path("/myrestapi")
@Stateless
public class Authentication {

    @POST
    @Path("/myendpoint")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response myEndPoint(@HeaderParam("Content-Type") String contentType, String body){

      return Response.status(200)
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
                .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600")
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .entity("{ke1:'val1'}").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }


}
```

Whenever I call this.gateway.getData('aparam'); because I have in the debug mode my local server I cannot receive any request (from Postman it works fine). So it seems that it's from the client side that it doesnt send any request.

From Chrome from the network tools I have the following:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: install CORS extension in chrome. Also search for CORS plugin on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS is an error raised by browsers to prevent unauthorized cross-origin requests to protect the end-users of the website - so, for example, chrome will raise it, but chromium which is run by Ionic will not - so it should only happen in the browser.

you have two options here:

1. Install a CORS chrome extension - since the mobile version will never get cors errors, it will be fine.
2. Enable CORS in glassfish/JEE, take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343892/glassfish-how-to-set-access-control-allow-origin-header) for details on how to do it - you can see in the response that you got from the server (response headers) - no `access-control-allow-origin` header is returned.

Comment: Actually it was the CORS chrome extension. Now it works! Thanks